# LuaLatex, \includespread and libreoffice table with %

Tags: luatex

I've using LuaLatex for the last couple of days and been enjoying it despite of lack of documentation on \includespread. Nevertheless, got it to work for tables that don't have a percentage value (e.g.: 10% in a cell).

Is this a bug or a feature? How can I include a spreadsheet with percentage values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `10\%` You have to escape the `%` character

Comment: @Herbert Escaping with a "\"... Should've thought about that...
Using that, I'll have to duplicate any cell with a % to have a value that can be use to calculate stuff (hidden) and another to show (and be imported by includespread).

Comment: give a _complete_ and small example which shows your problem.

Comment: I think that the problem is with my `odsfile` package, respective version which is on CTAN, it can include open document spreadsheets and it has problem with character escaping. I should probably upload current development version, which solves these problems, although some bugs are still unsolved

Comment: I uploaded odsfile v0.4 to CTAN, bug with escaping is fixed in this release

Comment: @Herbert After updating my latex installation with michal.h21 github files, I still have an issue. I've uploaded a complete small exmaple to https://mega.co.nz/#!2RMCmYZR!-7dse2P5OuYMRYRIyzf3SEjtish72KUrzfmnWZ1_Ui0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

OP provided some test files, which showed few new issues. Those issues should be fixed now and updated package will find its way to CTAN and TeX Live soon, hopefully.

There is one issue with your code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \label{tab:stuff_cal}
  \centering     
  \begin{tabular}
    \includespread[file=calcs.ods, template=table_3c, columns=head] 
  \end{tabular}            
  \caption{Stuff calculated in a ods.}
\end{table}
```

you use `\begin{tabular}` without specifying columns, and TeX parser reads next token, which is `\includespread`. So it is newer executed. As you defined template `table_3c` as full tabular environment, you really don't need to start tabular here and just use `\includespread` alone.

Result of your sample:

[image]

---

I suppose you are talking about my `odsfile` package. Behaviour you describe is a bug which was fixed some time ago, but I haven't posted fixes to `CTAN` until today (I am really bad in posting stuff to CTAN). So thank you for remind me. Some other bugs were fixed as well in this release, so you should update your TeXLive distribution as soon as the update gets here.

[image]

you can see from the screenshot from PDF generated from `ODS` spreadsheet that not only special characters such as `%` or `$` works, but also some basic styles such as **bold** text works, as well as external links

Comment: Got the odsfile sty/lua files from your git and was able to include almost all tables, except for one. I've created a set of files, ziped and put those in a mega share: https://mega.co.nz/#!2RMCmYZR!-7dse2P5OuYMRYRIyzf3SEjtish72KUrzfmnWZ1_Ui0  Thanks

Comment: @Marc there was bug in your code as well as there were bugs in `odsfile`. I will add details about fix for your code here, updated `odsfile` is on Github and I uploaded it to CTAN as well

Comment: Thank you for the lightning fast fix! I can confirm the issue is solved. Thank you also for pointing that bug. Odsfile is, in my opinion, something crucial while preparing documents with large amounts of data stored in a spreadsheet.